# ORA-19011: Character string buffer too small ORA-06512 Oracle

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql

Hi I am getting the below error.What should I make change so as to accommodate the maximum size for this variable

[Error] Execution (1: 1): ORA-19011: Character string buffer too small
ORA-06512: at line 4

```
DECLARE
c_var CLOB;
BEGIN
SELECT 
RTRIM(XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT(E,'''' ||code|| ''' AS '||code||',')ORDER BY code).extract('//text()'),',')

INTO c_var FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Code from table_A);

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (c_var);
END;
```

Comment: What type is `code` and what is it's value. If it is a `clob`, you can't just concatenate them.

Comment: @PatrickHofman Code is varchar2 maximum size going to 5

Comment: Can you cut the statement in pieces to determine what call fails? (something we can execute as well)

Comment: @PatrickHofman I'm sorry , I didn't get you .It fails at the select statement.

Comment: @PatrickHofman: Is there any other way to conacatenate by comma in Oracle 11.1..I want to concatenate approx 400-500 rows of one column and put it in a variable

Comment: You can use `dbms_lob.append` for larger text variables.

Answer (score 0):

If u want to concatenate the distinct values from code column in table_A. Please use the below query.

```
select listagg(Code, ',') within group (order by Code)
from (   select distinct Code 
          from table_A)
```